# template specialization in C++ file

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++

I have the following code

```cpp
// Foo.h
class A
{
public:
template<typename T> 
void doSomething(const T& myT);

};

extern template void A::doSomething<double>(const double& myDouble);
extern template void A::doSomething<int>(const int& myDouble);

template <typename T>
void A::doSomething(const T& myT)
{
static_assert(/* properties of T */);
throw std::exception();
}
```

And I want to define specialization in .cpp file

```cpp
template <>
void A::doSomething<double>(const double&)
{
 // ... 
}

template <>
void A::doSomething<int>(const int&)
{
 // ... 
}
```

Compiles perfectly fine on msvc C++17, but does not compile on gcc 11.2.1.

Error message is:

```
error: specialization of 'void A::doSomething(const T&) [with T = double]' after instantiation
```

Question essentialy is - how specialize a template in the .cpp file?

Comment: ooo right, will do

Comment: I think you are confusing _template specialization_ with _explicit instantiation_.

Comment: but I specialze the template, it has a function body different from the genertic template body. In any case I need to solve this issue, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your problem is that `template void A::doSomething<double>` is instantiation (you tell the compiler that in your library there will be code for that template, but it should be same as the main template - eg. you when want to curb down code bloat. Explicit specialization (for a particular type) is declared `template<> void A::doSomething<double>`, note the extra `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the template specializations in the header file:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <exception>

class A {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void doSomething(const T& myT);
};

template<> void A::doSomething<double>(const double& myDouble);
template<> void A::doSomething<int>(const int& myDouble);

template<typename T>
void A::doSomething(const T& myT) {
    throw std::exception();
}
```

This lets you keep the implementations of the specializations in the `.cpp` file.

---

Sidenote: Instead of unconditionally throwing an exception in the primary function template, you could just remove that implementation to get a link error if someone tries using it. That would also mean that you can remove the declarations of the specializations:

```cpp
#pragma once

class A {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void doSomething(const T& myT);
};
```

Comment: @Michael You're welcome! Please let me know if something doesn't work out.

Comment: I have no idea why my solution didn't work, but yours works so thank you!

Comment: @Michael Great, you're welcome. I don't know why it works in MSVC. You don't declare specializations like in your original try where you did an explicit instantiation declaration. Perhaps it's an extension to the language in msvc.